# Javascript Regex find string between _ and -

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to work out the regex to get the `en` part of the string`word_en-gb`

I'm using `.match();` e.g.

```
var string = "word_en-gb";
string.match(/(?<=\_)(.*?)(?=\-)/);
```

This `(?<=\_)(.*?)(?=\-)` works on `regex101.com` but when I use it in my code I get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=_)(.*?)(?=-)/: Invalid group`

and

`\_(.*?)\-`matches on regex101 but produces `_en-,en`

Comment: Look behind assertions aren't available in JS. See [MDN's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lookbehind isn't available in Javascript regex. You can use captured group #1:

```
var string = "word_en-gb";
string.match(/_(.*?)(?=-)/);
//=> ['_en', 'en']
```

Or negation:

```
string.match(/_([^-]*)/);
//=> ['_en', 'en']
```

Comment: why does it return an array and no just `en`?

Comment: Because `String#match` method returns an array with match and all captured groups.